# Is there a way to turn a PGP key into its semi-prime counterpart?

Tags: rsa, public-key, pgp

From my understanding of PGP keys they use the RSA algorithms to encrypt/decrypt messages. So, I know that the RSA algorithms use a semi-prime number to encrypt/decrypt messages. So, what I was wondering is: is the PGP key that you see the semi-prime number, and if so, how do you convert it back to the number.

This is my public key (I think):

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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 =Y2jy
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Sorry, if I am totally confused and actually know nothing.

Comment: [Similar question on Security.SE for GnuPG](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/33424/9079) (which is [largely PGP compatible](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#compatible))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenPGP message you posted is a *signature*, not a key. As it was issued by GnuPG, I assume you're using GnuPG anyway. To export your public key, run `gpg --armor --export [key-id]`. `--armor` wraps the output in a base64-like encoding (like the signature block you provided in your question), otherwise you'll get binary output. If you don't know your key-id, you can look it up through `gpg --list-keys`, possibly followed by a search pattern on a user ID you added -- for example your mail address.

The public key also contains user IDs, certifications, subkeys, ... and can be rather lengthy. The beginning of my own public key export:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1

mQQNBFDaK/sBIADm2gjnw7aPoNIoCy7gj85btwZU+zGkvtGonznlLrXELdU6zR3u
VHNCn9vAl6OoU32r+suFvGdX+7MjiPbGKwJFOvICpAVh6bV55+hdqJbS02cpPmJH
1BrrUAmm6ZVEybGd+II1pTI6Mt/SAI1E/59VIBdC/1AwsxQtCTFeyaLqTdyd1FhQ
chkjcvdRHLb4cEqldAGqBL7SbiSNOP3p+vX8iwRN6PQ/erAGseawHnunuNIna+tA
t4te/MkI2uxT0KjsfF/NWHCB2aXt++egP8jGSaHRsVOlfHRVA3hHcUDlnW9DZRvG
QabHFcZvfcXAlNIRYKUzDIHEwpavAmHeGNhc2GNmDcDRF56741grVLNQT58vxK5o
dBLlC8ANckvE5ymdIKVPm+t5q10kFOAATcnmDV0oBt+15vzI3f+88yCoY904UWdY
[...]
```

If you want to dump the RSA primes, use the `pgpdump` tool (not included with GnuPG and has to be installed separately, but should be available readily packaged for all relevant distributions). To print the primes, you can directly pipe GnuPG's `--export` output into `pgpdump (consider storing the output to a file or piping into` less`, as the output can get really long):

```
gpg --export[key-id] | pgpdump -i
```

To understand the output of `pgpdump` (and the structure of OpenPGP messages), read [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880).